# update different values for each row in a table(sqlite)

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have an object, say a note, whose parameters I want to save in a table(content, size, width, height, etc). 
With having the sql string updateNotes:

```
UPDATE NOTES 
SET 
    CONTENT=@content, 
    POSX=@posX, 
    POSY=@posY,
    COLOR=@color,
    ORIENTATION=@orientation,
    HEIGHT=@height,
    WIDTH=@width,
    AUTHOR=@autho 
WHERE SESSION =@sid

    public void save()
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

        foreach (Note note in notes)
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand(updateNotes, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", note.getNoteItemContent());
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posX", note.getSvi().Center.X);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posY", note.getSvi().Center.Y);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", note.getColor());
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orientation", note.getSvi().Orientation);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", note.getSvi().ActualHeight);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@width", note.getSvi().ActualWidth);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", note.getAuthor());

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    comm.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { Microsoft.Surface.UserNotifications.RequestNotification("Database error", "Could not write to the database:" + e.Message); }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); }
                    listLoaded = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The method above does indeed update the rows in the table but with one value for all the rows that result from the query.

As a solution I thought of reading the note id first and then iterate (i++), but given that some notes(represented as rows in the table) may be deleted, the id will not necessarily follow a consecutive numbering.

Another solution was to query the database for all the rows(notes) for the given session(sid) and store their id in an array and the update the notes whose id can be found in the array.

Do you know of any other better optimised solution? Or do you reckon I should use the array for storing the id's of the rows to be updated and the apply  the query.

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do here. Presumably you have a bunch of note objects that are taken from the database and edited by the user, and you are trying to update the database to reflect those edits. If so, can't the note object include the id of the row to which it corresponds?

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to do. 
the note has an id, in the table but not in the object too, mainly because it is a primary key assigned by the database and is auto-increment, the issue would have been how to grab this id for each note upon creation.

Comment: When you are creating the note objects, you must be selecting the data from the database at that time (content, pos, etc.). Why can't you select the id as well, and store that in a property on the notes object. Then, when you do the update, you can include the id in the where clause and only update the one row corresponding to the given note.

Comment: fair point. just missed thinking out of the box honestly. What I did was creating the object with some default hardcoded values first and then calling the getters from the objects for inserting into the database. 
But thanks for the enlightenment Tom. 'cause now I'm inserting with the default values in the db first and the do a read for allocating them to the object through setters. 
Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: You should have suggested that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seem to have resolved this in the question's comments but just to be clear on the answer (and hopefully give you something to accept), here is a summary:

When creating note objects, the data constituting those notes is selected from the database. As well as selecting outward facing data such as the note colour and content, we also select the primary key of each note and store this as a property of the note object.

Now, when a note object is updated, you can include its id in the where clause for the corresponding update statement and hence only update the one row corresponding to the modified note.

Glad I could provide some "enlightenment" -- as you put it.